# Drupal content sharing between users

Tags: drupal, reference

I'm creating a website in which users can share their content with other users, so that only selected users can see your content.

The event content type has a User Reference field in which the users can tick the desired users to which to show the content. Is this a good solution? The problem is when trying to create a view, that shows those events.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, instead of using the "User Reference" data type in the share field, I had to use "Entity Reference". Then add the "Entity Reference" relationship in to the desired view and filter user = current user. Works like a charm. As far as I understood, the entity reference has search fields, so that I can search for the logged in user in the field :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a standard (good) way to implement this in Drupal is with the [User Relationships](http://dgo.to/user_relationships) module. Install User Relationships so that users can create new relationships with other users (eg. "friend", "can see some of my stuff", "can see all my stuff" etc.)

You'll need to create a custom module that extends access control permissions by checking for that the required relationship exists before showing or listing the content. This can be done with straight up procedural logic, but do pay attention to how you construct your iterative loops, so that your custom code will scale as your site grows in users.

Alternately, you could use the [Flag Friend](http://dgo.to/flag_friend) module, a lighter alternative to UR that lets you define flags between users in much the same fashion as UR, but without some of the additional complication.

Finally, depending on what your actual user case, you may want to look at [OG](http://drupal.org/project/og) (Organic Groups) which allows you to create groups of users who can share content within their group.

Comment: I'm already using the UR module, so that the user can share with friends only.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you may find doing this in code makes it easier to generate the views you need (than site-building with a UR field.) Also, not knowing your requirements it does seem your model should define a user-user relationship, not a property on the content type.

Comment: Users can share one type of content (Event), it's a social calendar website. Doesn't it seem wrong to create a user-user relationship for each piece of content?

Comment: Yes, user-user on every item would be a mess, I had thought this was a relationship on the bundle itself. If it's per item, this raises the question won't the users define sharing groups? (ie it's not going to be an arbitrary set of users for each item they share, but like most social sites, would be list or group based.)

Veering off technical implementation here, but this actually seems like an interesting UX. and it's not yet clear what the best data model would be.)

Comment: If using groups, there can be the problem what to do, if I don't want to invite the whole group, so I think sharing individually would be better. The site itself wont be online for long, it's just a project to simulate development. Seems that the only way is to write my own filter in php, but that is impossible because i don't know it + i have to get acquainted with how to write for drupal etc. If i will mange to solve this, i will tell..

Answer (score 1):

Drupal's node system provides an API to implement fine grainerd access control. This API is used by implementing [hook_node_grants()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7) and [hook_node_access_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7). Before you do so, take a look at the [Overview of Node Access modules](http://drupal.org/node/270000) to see if any meets your needs.

Comment: I have a problem with that - the view it self contains many pieces of content, as far as i understood, permissions will limit the whole view, or not? I'm thinking of a filter: if the logged in users name is in the events share field, then it shows up. How hards would it be to implement this?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward to implement if you use the user ID as grant ID. Also, consider asking questions related to Drupal on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm new to web-development, that's why I'm using drupal.

Comment: Agree with Oswald, seems like a good question for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/